# How to use lotusscript NotesDateTime object in search formula in Search method of NotesDatabase?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus

I want to use NotesDateTime object in search formula of search method of NOtesDatabase. Below is my code

```
Dim searchFormula5 As String
Dim modifiedAfter As New NotesDateTime("10/10/2010")
searchFormula5$= {PaPeriodEnd<@Today & PaPeriodEnd > modifiedAfter & PaStatus=Signed }  
Set collectionDocs=database1.Search(searchFormula5$,NOTHING,0)
```

I am not able to use `modifiedAfter` in search formula.
PaPeriodEnd is date item in documents in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it

`searchFormula5$ = {PaPeriodEnd < @Today & PaPeriodEnd > [10/10/2010] & PaStatus = Signed}`

Comment: Or if you are using a the object because it is really a variable value,
 then use {searchFormula5$ = {PaPeriodEnd < @Today & PaPeriodEnd > } + modifiedAfter.DateOnly() + { & PaStatus = Signed}

Comment: modifiedAfter is variable that's why I have to use the object. I found the solution. Same as your solution with little change. `searchFormula5$= {PaPeriodEnd<@Today &( PaPeriodEnd>@TextToTime("}& modifiedAfter.DateOnly()&{"))& PaStatus="Signed" }`